Variance of Random Variable Y which relies on X
I have the following question:
An urn contains a white balls and b black balls. Suppose $m$ random balls are taken out of the urn
without replacement, and then n more are taken out, where $m + n ≤ min(a, b)$. Let X and Y denote
the number of white balls in the first batch and in the second batch, respectively.
Calculate $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$.
Now for $X$ i know that $X \sim H(m,a,b)$, So its variance is known.
About Y I'm not sure on how to proceed.
Thanks in advanced!
Can I even conclude that Y is also hypergeometric with (n,a,b) parameters?

Any collection of $n$ balls is equally likely to be chosen as part of the second selection, so the same analysis you used for $X$ applies to $Y$.  That is to say, you may as well imagine that the $Y$ selection happened first. Of course, $X,Y$ are dependent variables, but you were not asked about that.

@lulu if I imagine that Y was chosen first, does it mean I should know the PMF for him? or should I only know information only about it's Variance?

A good approach is to get $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$, then use $Var(Y)=E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$.  You can use $E[Y^2]=E[E[Y^2|X]]$. Or if you prefer, $$E[Y^2]=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}E[Y^2|X=x]P[X=x]$$ In general, computations for a 2-stage experiment can be done by conditioning on the result of the first stage.

@Michael I haven't learnt this also, could we use some kind of symmetric in this question? as lulu suggested? I just don't understand what he fully meant :\

Suppose $A_1, A_2, ...$ is a partition of the sample space. Are you sure you have not learned the "law of total expectation"? It is $$E[Z]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E[Z|A_k]P[A_k]$$ If you like you can also use the law of total probability $P[Y=i]=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}P[Y=i|X=x]P[X=x]$.

@Michael I tried calculating it, but you get into a very ugly experssion.

I didn't really read the question, or perhaps I didn't think about it enough.  The question does not really require you to treat the problem in stages. You are told $m$ are taken, then $n$, but as Lulu's first comment says, who cares if $m$ are taken first or second? So indeed you can do this problem with no calculation at all.  If you know how to calculate $Var(X)$ in terms of the parameters then the calculation for $Var(Y)$ is the essentially the same (with different parameters).

@Michael get it, and i also think Y must be hypergeometric with the same parameters, but I dont understand how to prove this formally...

One intuition is to take $m+n$ total balls out of the original jar (equally likely over all options, but choosing none "first"). If you must assign some of them to be chosen "first," you can scramble these $m+n$ balls and randomly put them into two groups: one group of size $m$, the other group of size $n$. You can say the group of size $m$ was "chosen first" from the original jar, or you can say the group of size $n$ was "chosen first."

$ X \sim \textrm{Hypergeometric}(a+b, a, m)$
$ Y\mid X \sim \textrm{Hypergeometric}(a+b-m, a-X, n) $
Using the Law of Total Variance,
$\mathbb{V}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(Y \mid X)) + \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) $

I haven't learnt Law of Total Variance yet, and also, how did you figure out that $Y∣X∼Hypergeometric(a+b−m,a−X,n)$ ?

@user1516674 Notice that once you've picked m balls from the urn, you have (a+b-m) balls left in the urn, of which (a-X) are white, and you're going to pick n of them. So $Y \mid X$'s distribution comes directly from a description of the situation.
